# how to receive data using data-post in ruby on rails and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

```html
<a class="new_thread" data-post="<%= post.id %>">Button</a>
```

I was trying to send data to Javascript

```js
$('.new_thread').on('click', async evt => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        const $tgt = $(evt.target);
        const $anchor = $tgt.is('a') ? $tgt : $tgt.parents('a');
        const post_id = $anchor.attr('data-post');
        const thread = document.getElementById("new_thread_modal_" + post_id);

        if (thread.style.display === "none") {
            thread.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            thread.style.display = "none";
        }
    })
```

When I click on that button the javascript file isn't working. I got the following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (comments.self-05d964752f9f39ac858194974bab2f9f098c99c773368326d9bde8e452bae945.js?body=1:265)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle
```

Earlier, I was using onclick but, now I am trying to send data using data-post. When I had tried to print something in logcat I noticed I can getting output. But, how can I receive data which I sent using data-post?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.new_thread').on('click', async evt => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        const $tgt = $(evt.target);
        const post_id = $tgt.attr('data-post');
        const thread = document.getElementById("new_thread_modal_" + post_id);

        if (thread.style.display === "none") {
            thread.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            thread.style.display = "none";
        }
    })
```

This worked for me.